# how to add .bundle file to a nativescript plugin

Tags: plugins, nativescript

I have some thirdparty code I want to add to my nativescript (iOS) project.  The code consists of a .framework file and a .bundle file which contains a .momd file. I was thinking of adding this via a custom plugin, the docs are pretty clear on how to add the .framework file, but am not sure how I add and reference the bundle and underlying .momd file.  Does anyone have any experience of this that they can share please?

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time poring over the iOS interop documentation while working on my [nativescript-midi plugin](https://github.com/BinaryNate/nativescript-midi), but I don't recall seeing anything specifically on adding bundles or .momd files. If possible, I suggest you create a new "container" iOS framework project in which you can import your desired framework, bundle, and .momd file, and then import that combined framework project into your plugin via a Podfile. That's essentially the approach I took to import a C library in my project (the cocoa-midi-message-parser repo referenced by the Podfile in my plugin).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else needs to do this. I ended up using cocoapods [xcodeproj gem](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj) to inject my file into my workspace file.  A gist of the working code is [here](https://gist.github.com/sharpred/d7d049e80ba82dbbf0451e5ae3dc2f47).